# OPENCV, How to detect parking spots

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, detection, houghlinesp

I am trying to make a parking space detection system, I opened a question 2 days ago. It didn't work what ever I tried, I decided I start again with it. I have did alot of things to make this better, currently it only detects straight line, and I want to get this to detect parking spots. I wanted to know how can I do this?

I think there are some major problems with the method I am currently using

[image: ORIGINAL IMAGE]

[image: HOW IT WORKS RIGHT NOW]

I try using a car `haarcascade` to detect cars and not drawing the lines but it doesn't seem to work. This is all i tried, because i couldn't think of any other way of doing this

Code

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

example_image = 'Data/Input/carPark.mp4'
car_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier('Data/Input/haarcascade_car.xml')
img = cv.VideoCapture(example_image)

while img.isOpened():
 ret, frame = img.read()
 if not ret:
     break;
 img_gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 cars = car_cascade.detectMultiScale(img_gray, 1.1, 3)
 img_blur = cv.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (5, 3), cv.BORDER_DEFAULT)
 edges = cv.Canny(img_blur, 150, 150)
 dilated = cv.dilate(edges, (5, 5), iterations=3)
 lines = cv.HoughLinesP(dilated, 1, np.pi / 180, threshold=100, minLineLength=100, maxLineGap=10)

# Check if lines were found
 if lines is not None:
     if len(cars) == 0:
         for line in lines:
             x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]  # Access the points of the line
             cv.line(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)

 if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
 cv.imshow("Image", frame)

img.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am also really new to openCV

Comment: Anyone?, i am not able to figure this out

Comment: You have to play around with values such as `threshold`, `minLineLength`, and `maxLineGap`. I can merely do in Linux.

Comment: Can you post the original image?

Comment: its the original image, that is how it looks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bmox9.jpg


I want to implement that it detects the empty spots, how am i supposed to do that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77549191/car-parking-detection-system-issue-opencv/ Without rectangle.

Comment: Can we use yolo models to check for parking spots?
Because there is no way algorithms will work on all types of parking spaces

Comment: https://imgur.com/IA12H3C


Here you go

Comment: That perfect. Can u put in  the original image in ur question?

Comment: yes done, i edited it. Can you help?

Comment: just paint a big X on the parking spaces and go for that

Comment: You used video instead of  image.